# why I can't access other static member function in member function?

Tags: python

I come from C++, and I want to access another static member function in one member function.

S1:

```
class Test:
    @staticmethod
    def hello():
        print("static method is on")

    def hey(self):
        hello()
```

output:

error, the hello() isn't defined

S2:

```
def hello():
    print("hello outside")

def hey():
    hello()
```

output:

ok

Answer (score 1):

From the [staticmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) documentation:

> A static method does not receive an implicit first argument.
>
> ...
>
> It can be called either on the class (such as C.f()) or on an instance (such as C().f()).

You still need to self reference the object. Otherwise, the interpreter will be looking for a top level function named `hello`.

```
class Test:
    @staticmethod
    def hello():
        print("static method is on")

    def hey(self):
        self.hello()


t = Test()
t.hey()

out: "static method is on"

Test.hey()

out: "static method is on"
```

Hopefully, this example explains better.

```
def hello():
    print("this is not the static method you are loking for")


class Test:
    @staticmethod
    def hello():
        print("static method is on")

    def hey(self):
        hello()


t = Test()
t.hey()

out: "this is not the static method you are loking for"
```

Comment: actually , it only look up `hello` in the top level namespace. but it doesn't look up inside the class.  why does this happen

Comment: The interpreter needs to know where to look for in order to call your function. The `staticmethod` decorator binds the function in the class namespace. Therefore, you need to reference the class or the object.

Comment: @LFBuildAMountain this is a general principle in Python that's not specific to static methods. Unlike Java or C++, you need to do the same (explicitly refer to self or another instance or class) for all methods and attributes.